# Average value along with 5 top maximum values for each record

Tags: sql, database, db2

For this example data:

```
First Name | Last Name | Count | datetime
----------------------------------------------------
John       | Mac       | 5     | 2019-07-09 01:00:01
Drew       | G         | 6     | 2019-07-09 01:01:01
John       | Mac       | 10    | 2019-07-09 01:11:01
John       | Mac       | 15    | 2019-07-09 01:12:01
John       | Mac       | 16    | 2019-07-09 01:13:01
John       | Mac       | 2     | 2019-07-09 01:14:01
Drew       | G         | 16    | 2019-07-09 01:03:01
Drew       | G         | 26    | 2019-07-09 01:08:01
Drew       | G         | 8     | 2019-07-09 02:01:01
Drew       | G         | 10    | 2019-07-09 05:01:01
Drew       | G         | 11    | 2019-07-09 08:01:01
```

I can use this query to get the average count for each person grouped by date:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, date(datetime), avg(count)
from table
where date(datetime) between '2019-07-08' and '2019-07-08'
group by firstname, lastname, date(datetime)
```

How do I write a query to include the five highest counts for each (name, date) combination? I want to produce output like:

```
First Name | Last Name | Avg_count| date       | max1 | max1_datetime       |  max2 | max2_datetime       | max 3 | max3_datetime       | max4 | max4_datetime       | max5 |max5_ datetime
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John       | mac       | 9        | 2019-07-09 | 16   | 2019-07-09 01:13:01 | 15     | 2019-07-09 01:12:01 | 10    | 2019-07-09 01:11:01 | 5    | 2019-07-09 01:00:01 | 2    | 2019-07-09 01:14:01
```

Comment: "...for each record..." -- what do you mean?

Comment: Readability fixes and clarifying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select firstname, lastname, date(datetime), avg(count),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then count end) as count_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then datetime end) as datetime_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then count end) as count_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then datetime end) as datetime_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then count end) as count_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then datetime end) as datetime_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then count end) as count_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then datetime end) as datetime_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then count end) as count_5,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then datetime end) as datetime_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, date(datetime) order by count desc) as seqnum
      from table t
      where datetime >= '2019-07-08' and
            datetime < '2019-07-09'
     ) t
group by firstname, lastname, date(datetime);
```

Note that I changed the date comparison as well.  This make it more compatible for using indexes.

Comment: can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059966/top-2-max-value-excluding-duplicate-values